# Android remote view display images from the web?

Tags: android, android-widget, remoteview, stackview

Does any know of a tutorial or something similar to help create a Remote View wigdet like this...

[image]

I followed through the development guide on doing StackView widget. I did it but i dont know how to display images in the Stack like the example news 360 does.

All i want to do is display images in the remote view from a url.

Comment: See my answer. Hope it will lead you to solution

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28255913/2034822