# how to design a screen like over riding of views?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gallery

I have few advertisement details with me.i need to display those advertisements like override on each other.while swipe the advertisement need to display the other advertisement which is existed below the current advertisement.

[image: please see this image]

[this is also same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894147/android-remote-view-display-images-from-the-web) but didn't get the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my opinion:
1) a single view contains the top details of your ad
2) make a picture as background of the view, and make it looks like many views override on each other
3) when you detect a gesture means swipe to anther, create a popwindow contains the same layout and same date just as detail view does
4) fill the detail view with other data

PS: if the swipe gesture is aborted, dispose the popwindow and fill the deatil view with origin data